# Why the reduce function in CouchDB is not returning an array?

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

My reduce function in CouchDB is made to return an array but when I run the Couch query i get something like 6.9533536257605e-310 instead of getting an array.

I have tested my code in online javascript editor and when i console.log() the value returned is an array but in CouchDb i am not getting that array.

Map function

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.docType="Asset" && doc.owner){
    emit(doc.owner,doc.name);

  }
}
```

Reduce function

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {

  if (rereduce) {
    s=values[0];
    for ( var i of values){
      s=s.concat(i);
      s=[...new Set(s)];
    }
   return s;

  } else {
    var s=[];
    for ( var i of values){
      s.push(i);
  }
  s=[...new Set(s)];
  return s;
}
```

Expected output

```
Tom     ["laptop","mobile"]
Harry   ["bike","scooter"]
```

Actual output

```
Tom     6.9533536257605e-310
Harry   6.9525841588194e-310
```

Comment: How are you testing this function that produces the output you see?

Comment: Actual output was returned by CouchDb MapReduce function whereas expected output was realized by passing  values by self in an online editor and console logging the output. Values to be passed were determined from the outputs of the map function which was as expected. The problem is only with the outputs returned by the reduce function.